# How can I cause the latest touch event to interrupt a prior event in Cocos2D?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, multitouch

In Cocos2D for iPhone, I want the latest touch event to interrupt another and ignore the last touch. Let me know if I need to elaborate more, but basically my game consists of a lot of finger dragging, and if the player ever switched fingers, there may be some overlap, and for the way things are setup, it may detect it as a new touch.

I think I have things almost on the right track, but my third touch does not work correctly. For instance:

- Touch A begins and held
- Touch B begins and held
- Touch A let go
- Touch A begins and held <-This should
  interrupt Touch B

In my delegate I put [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]; because I believe I need multiple touches enabled.

In my CCLayer class with my added map and sprite I am using targeted touch delegate (i.e. ccTouchBegan NOT ccTouchesBegan, etc)

I am accessing a touch object with touch = [[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];, however I don't have much understanding what index is considered the latest touch or even a process to always get the latest touch.

Comment: as much as I know all touches keep their numbers until they end.
consider the below senario:

*touchA begin -> index 0

*touchB begin -> A = 0 , B = 1

*touchA end -> B = 1

*touchC begin -> C = 0 , B = 1

*touchB end -> C = 0


and their index is always the same for each of touchbegin ,touchmoved, and touch end.

Comment: Okay, maybe what I didn't understand was that when you do something like touch = [[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];, you're actually SETTING that touch to index 0? I thought that meant the touch equaled the touch event at index 0.

Comment: that means touch at index 0, but when the second touch starts and the first touch not ended yet cocos2d will store it in index 1

Comment: Interesting, let me work with this some more and I'll get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: So in the end, how can you prove what is the latest touch?

Comment: I'm going to look into UITouch's timestamp that it can return.

Answer (score -1):

Look at these links, they might help:

- http://lethain.com/touch-detection-in-cocos2d-iphone/
- http://en.saturngod.net/detecting-touch-events-in-cocos2d-iphone-ganb
- http://www.cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/handling_events.html

I would try to do it this way:

1. store the events in a list
2. examine this list in a function which is called after all input has been processed (there might be an event handler for it).